# How to substitute predicate value by a variable using LXML find() with Python 3.6

Tags: python-3.x, xpath, lxml

I am new to Python coding. I am able to create the output XML file. I want to use a variable which holds a string value and pass it to 'predicate' of  'find()'. Is this achievable? How to make this work?

I am using LXML package with Python 3.6. Below is my code. Area of problem is commented at the end of the code.

```
import lxml.etree as ET

# Create root element
root = ET.Element("Base", attrib={'Name': 'My Base Node'})
# Create first child element
FirstElement = ET.SubElement(root, "FirstNode", attrib={'Name': 'My First Node', 'Comment':'Hello'})

# Create second child element
SecondElement = ET.SubElement(FirstElement, "SecondNode", attrib={'Name': 'My Second Node', 'Comment': 'World'})

# Create XML file
XML_data_as_string = ET.tostring(root, encoding='utf8')
with open("TestFile.xml", "wb") as f:
    f.write(XML_data_as_string)

# Variable to substitute in second portion of predicate
NewValue = "My Second Node"

# #### AREA OF PROBLEM ###
# Question. How to pass variable 'NewValue' in the predicate?

# Gives "SyntaxError: invalid predicate"
x = root.find("./FirstNode/SecondNode[@Name={subs}]".format(subs=NewValue))

# I commented above line and reexecuted the code with this below line 
# enabled. It gave "ValueError: empty namespace prefix must be passed as None, 
# not the empty string"
x = root.find("./FirstNode/SecondNode[@Name=%s]", NewValue)
```

Comment: Looks like you’re missing a single quote after `@Name=`.

Comment: Good point. In fact, this single quote in @Name= should be removed. Suppose, if I had  @Name='{subs}' then {subs} is treated as string, which is not intended. Now, using @Name={subs} gives "SyntaxError: invalid predicate". i.e, using                                                              
x = root.find("./FirstNode/SecondNode[@Name={subs}]".format(subs=NewValue))                                                                                    any other solutions/hints?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As [Daniel Haley](https://stackoverflow.com/users/317052/daniel-haley) said - you're missing a single quotes in `@Name={subs}`.

The following line works for me:

```
x = root.find("./FirstNode/SecondNode[@Name='{subs}']".format(subs=NewValue))
```

Since you use *Python 3.6*, you can utilize [*f-strings*](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.6.html#pep-498-formatted-string-literals):

```
x = root.find(f"./FirstNode/SecondNode[@Name='{NewValue}']")
```

Comment: Both the lines of code works for me. Thanks a ton Mike !

Comment: @mzjn: Accepted the answer. Being my first question in this forum, learning the protocols.

Answer (score 0):

The "proper" way to solve this would be to use [XPath variables](https://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xpath-19991116/#NT-VariableReference), which are not supported by `find()` (and consequently, aren't supported by `xml.etree` from the standard library either) but [are supported by `xpath()`](https://lxml.de/xpathxslt.html#the-xpath-method).

```
NewValue = "AJL's Second Node" # Uh oh, that apostrophe is going to break something!!
x_list = root.xpath("./FirstNode/SecondNode[@Name=$subs]", subs=NewValue)
x = x_list[0]
```

This avoids any sort of issue you might otherwise run into with quoting and escaping.

---

The main caveat of this method is namespace support, since it doesn't use the bracket syntax of find.

```
x = root.find("./{foobar.xsd}FirstNode")
# Brackets are doubled to avoid conflicting with `.format()`
x = root.find("./{{foobar.xsd}}FirstNode/SecondNode[@Name='{subs}']".format(subs=NewValue))
```

Instead, you must specify those in a separate dict:

```
ns_list = {'hello':'foobar.xsd'}
x_list = root.xpath("./hello:FirstNode/SecondNode[@Name=$subs]", namespaces=ns_list , subs=NewValue)
x = x_list[0]
```